# HTML5 Canvas колесо фортуны

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, canvas

Задача распределить текст по 8ми секторам барабана и при вращении картинки-фона, вращать этот текст с фоном синхронно. В скрипт файле(см. [пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/RV1wfeH8mtYZItpRGdP1?p=preview)) На строке 67 делаю обход массива с этими значениями, и вывожу нужный текст. Но проблематично равномерно нарисовать этот текст. Фоновая картинка уже содержит некоторые значения, но это не выход, так как эти цифры динамические, и постоянно рисовать картинку не выход. Спасибо.

```
Вот из строки 67: на картинке красным обвел, то что получилось

//    ВЫВОД И ТРАНСФОРМИРОВАНИЕ ТЕКСТ
prizes.forEach(function (value, key) {
    surfaceContext.save();
    surfaceContext.font = 'normal 28px Sans-Serif';
    //surfaceContext.rotate(Math.PI / 2 * rotate);
    surfaceContext.rotate(rotate);
    surfaceContext.translate(0, 0);
    surfaceContext.textAlign = "right";
    surfaceContext.fillText(value.name, labelXposition, labelYposition);
    labelXposition = labelXposition + 30;
    labelYposition = labelYposition - 30;
    //rotate = rotate + 2;
    newy = newy + 20;
    newx = newx + 20;
    surfaceContext.restore();
});
```

p.s. Извиняюсь если не совсем доходчиво расписал, пишите буду дополнять.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Поворачиваешь канвас на нужный угол `pi/4 * (i+.5)` и рисуешь текст в одном и том же месте для каждого i. Центрируй текст относительно точки `(r*3/4, r/2)`.